# Im referencing a constant class static variables, but when i do the values somehow change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reference, static

Here is my constant class that i reference from.
Below that is the class that is trying to use the reference.

Here is the error message im getting.

The Type initializer for ConstantClass threw an exception ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

Any ideas about it?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]

    public static class ConstantClass
    {
        public static int positiveInt = 10;
        public static int negativeInt = -10;
        public static long positivePastLimitInt = unchecked((int)2147483648);
        public static long negativePastLimitInt = unchecked((int)-2147483649);
        public static int zeroInt = 0;


        public static char lowerChar = 'c';
        public static char spaceChar = ' ';
        public static char symbolChar = '@';
        public static char numberChar = '1';
        public static char upperChar = 'D';

        public static string lowerString = "hello";
        public static string upperString = "HELLO";
        public static string emptyString = "";
        public static string spaceString = " ";
        public static string tabString = "    ";
        public static string symbolString = "!^&";
        public static string nullString = null;

        public static short positiveShort = 10;
        public static short negativeShort = -10;
        public static short zeroShort = 0;
        public static int positivePastLimitShort = unchecked((short)32768);
        public static int negativePastLimitShort = unchecked((short)-32769);

        public static long positiveLong = 10;
        public static long negativeLong = -10;
        public static long zeroLong = 0;
        public static Int64 positivePastLimitLong = (long)2147483648;
        public static Int64 negativePastLimitLong = (long)-2147483649;

        public static double positiveDouble = 10.0;
        public static double negativeDouble = -10.0;
        public static double zeroDouble = 0.0;
        public static double positiveLimitDouble = double.MaxValue;
        public static double negativeLimitDouble = double.MinValue;

        public static float positiveFloat = 10.0F;
        public static float negativeFloat = -10.0F;
        public static float zeroFloat = 0.0F;
        public static double positivePastLimitFloat = (float)float.MaxValue + 1;
        public static double negativePastLimitFloat = (float)float.MinValue - 1;

        public static bool positiveBool = true;
        public static bool negativeBool = false;


        //Here is the variable im trying to use.
        public static decimal positiveDecimal = 10.0m;
        public static decimal negativeDecimal = -10.0m;
        public static decimal zeroDecimal = 0.0m;
        public static decimal positivePastLimitDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(80000000000000E+40);
        public static decimal negativePastLimitDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(-8000000000000E-40);
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ByteDecimalTests
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void DecimalToBytes_WhenDecimalIsPositive()
        {
            //This is where i reference the constant class
            Decimal positiveDecimal = ConstantClass.positiveDecimal;
            //Decimal positiveDecimal = 12.98m;
            String positiveDecimalString = positiveDecimal.ToString();

            byte[] positiveDecimalArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(positiveDecimalString);
            byte[] array = ByteDecimal.DecimalToBytes(positiveDecimal);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(positiveDecimalArray));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(array));
            Assert.AreEqual(array, positiveDecimalArray);

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have the same problem on all your "past limit" values. The ones that won't throw are the `unchecked` ones, but they aren't doing what you may think, they are simply rolling over. If you check the value of them, they are not what you set them to be. You can't force a type to use a value larger than what it is designed to hold, you need to catch the `OverflowException`.

Comment: how could i test an overflow case then? I mean if a method takes an int and i want to try and break it with overflow, what could i pass it? Or is that not a realistic idea? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to test an overflow, make a method that takes an int, then add one to it inside the method. The method will throw an overflow exception. You can test for the exception in your test class to make sure it was thrown. In the method itself, you should verify that what you are about to do with the input won't overflow, or catch the overflow if you want to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a great and simple idea...just needed another perspective. I appreciate the help!

Comment: By the way `positivePastLimitLong` is incorrect: this is the limit of an `int` (`Int32`) not a `long` (`Int64`). The limit of a `long` (`Int64`) is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

Comment: I went back and realized that since @RonBeyer 's solution was quite nice in my opinion, i switched the values to just do the type.maxvalue and type.minvalue, Good eye though, I had not seen that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 public static decimal positivePastLimitDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(80000000000000E+40)
 public static decimal negativePastLimitDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(-8000000000000E-40);
```

You cannot store such big numbers on a decimal. Use float or double for that.

The [maximum value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can store in a decimal is: 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.

Comment: i need a value that is larger than a decimal, but that i can cast as a decimal. I have not been able to find how to do that. I need to test overflows. 

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to look for some external solutions, maybe this will work for you: https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136

Comment: i dont want to have to import all that code just for this small issue. I appreciate the link. Im looking for a quick fix if there is one. Thanks!

Comment: You can do Convert.ToDecimal(double.MaxValue) but it will fail as well at runtime. Don use static values for this, just use the expresion instead on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you to understand what you are doing, and so you could decide how to solve it. I'll take the short as the easier case to study, but the same can be said for every other case.

From your code:
    public static int positivePastLimitShort = unchecked((short)32768);

A short is internally stored as a 16 bits value, 15 bits for data and 1 bit for the sign.

sign b14 b13 b12 b11 b10 b09 b08 b07 b06 b05 b04 b03 b02 b01 b00

When you try to use a value that needs more than 15 bits to be represented, an overflow will occur.
32768 in binary form is 1000000000000000
but you cannot use the bit15, which is reserved for the sign in shorts (in ushort you can use all 16 bits, as no bit is reserved for sign).

You could even supress the cast and the unchecked, and just do:

```
public static int positivePastLimitShort = 32768;
```

as an int uses internally 32 bits, 1 for sign and 31 for data.

This is working as you have a value type that can store bigger numbers.

So, using an int for shorts passing the limit, using long for ints passing the limits, and so on. The problem would be to handle numbers passing the limits of the bigger capacity types, as long, double or decimal. For these cases you need a different way.